# Master Data Services 2019 Create Model Error

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I have installed Master Data Services 2019 and have the Database and Website configured and running, overall everything seems to be setup correctly.
But when I try to create a model, I get an error. Hovering over the icon all it says is Error. Has anyone run into this before?

I am using the built in Super User account (the one I installed MDS as)

I have given the Super User Account full DB permissions in SQL and, just for testing, assigned all MDS functions to it too

**Updated for clarity**. I see the error log file, but when I try to create the model it does not write to the error log file nor does it create a new one. So I can't find what the error actually is. Do I need to modify the web.config file to allow for different error logging for this? or some other config file?

The error log part of the web.config is below. Note I edited the config file to write to the folder ErrorLog just so I could be sure I was seeing the correct error files.

```
<sources>
  <!-- Adjust the switch value to control the types of messages that should be logged. 
       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.sourcelevels
       Use the a switchValue of Verbose to generate a full log. Please be aware that 
       the trace file can get quite large very quickly -->
  <source name="MDS" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <!-- Set a directory path where the service account you chose while setting up Master Data Services has read and write privileges.
           Default path is MDSTempDir in WebApplication folder, for example C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication
           New log file will be created everyday or every 10 mb.
           When directory size hits the 200mb limitation, the oldest file will be deleted.-->
      <add name="FileTraceListener" type="Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Core.Logging.FileTraceListener, Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Core" initializeData="DirectoryPath = ErrorLog; FileSizeInMb = 10; MaxDirectorySizeInMb = 200" />
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

Comment: By "can't find" presumably you've checked the locations from the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/tracing-master-data-services?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/955597/master-data-services-2019-error-creating-model.html)

Comment: I have tried several things in the web config and I can't get it to write to the log when I get this error.  I have even set the log level to "All" and still no log. 

Has anyone seen this error or problem before